# When did YouTube add preview thumbnails?

Tags: youtube

I recently noticed that video thumbnails now animate when hovered over on the homepage. It's a convenient feature which I hadn't really noticed until just today.

**How long has YouTube had animated thumbnails? When was this feature added?**

[image: Animated thumbnails]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How long has YouTube had animated thumbnails? When was this feature added?

This question is actually harder to answer than it may seem at first.

[The official announcement of it was on June 29](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/_l6l7EbHoKc), however: This was just the announcement that this feature is rolling out to a large-scale experiment. There have been various experiments with animated thumbnails for quite a while; YouTube Gaming had them since launch in 2015 and the main YouTube desktop app had small-scale experiments going on since at least summer 2016. And on the other end of the scale, the feature took a while to roll out as well (I'm not sure if it even *is* fully rolled out at this point), so there may be people still not having it.

So, the answer can be "Since YT:G launched", "Since summer 2016", "since June 29, 2017" and "not yet", depending on how you define "added".

---

On a related note, this is one of the reasons why the mobile apps only say something among the lines "bug fixes and improvements": At any given time, a user is in 40+ different experiments (most of them backend), so it's hard to even make a changelog.